# How to get performance LOG on EDGE driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver, selenium4

Hello i am trying to using same code to retrieve performance log from both Chrome and Edge to scan for errors , however for edge i am getting
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: log type 'performance' not found
(Session info: MicrosoftEdge=96.0.1054.34)

```
        case "EDGE":
                System.out.println("Launching Edge Browser");
    
                HashMap<String, Object> EdgePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                EdgePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
                EdgePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadPath);
                EdgeOptions Edgeoptions = new EdgeOptions();
                Edgeoptions.setCapability("prefs", EdgePrefs);
                Edgeoptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

                LoggingPreferences EdgelogPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
                EdgelogPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
                EdgelogPrefs.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.ALL);
                EdgelogPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
                Edgeoptions.setCapability("enableNetwork",true);
                Edgeoptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, EdgelogPrefs);
                Edgeoptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS,true);
              
                WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
        
                driver = new EdgeDriver(Edgeoptions);

                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TimeOut,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                break;
```

Code to retrieve the performance log

```
       LogEntries logs = WD.manage().logs().get("performance");
```

This line of code cause the org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: log type 'performance' not found
(Session info: MicrosoftEdge=96.0.1054.34)